# Mass Replacing HTML Article Values

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have a question about mass replacing article values

I want to run some code up to 5000 times.

```
//div[@id='example']/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/section/article[31]/button/span[2]
```

I want a program or whatever to replace the article[31] with article [32],[33],[34],[35] --till--> [5000]

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Please post a [mcve] with relevant HTML

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: You could use one of the technologies you specified either Front End Programming like JavaScript or Back End Programming like Java, but if you have existing HTML Code as you mentioned "replace article" then you can use JavaScript you will need a counter and then get the element by tag name article at the desired index and replace the value, cheers.